# XSL Fo - Speacial characters

Tags: xslt, pdf-generation, xmldocument, xsl-fo

I am designing an xsl form, my source pdf contains 'Diamond' symbols

1. I need to know how to use/create diamond character using xsl(is there any font family i can configure and use/can i get the symbol using Unicode characters).
2. Also how to use other special characters in xsl forms. need to know how to create white space also
   [image: List item]

Comment: For 2., it isn't clear what you mean by create whitespace. If you're looking to preserve whitespace there are fo attributes like linefeed-treatment='preserve'; or if you're looking to insert spaces use &#x0A; for a non-breaking space.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that some Unicode characters can be a bit tricky to use since a lot of fonts don't have certain glyphs. You know the glyph (the diamond) is missing from the font when you see the error WARNING: *Glyph "◆" (0x25c6, blackdiamond) not available in font*.

Here's a small example using a fo:inline to change to a font that has the glyph. I set the fo:root font family so the the entire document defaults to SansSerif; also the fo:page-sequence is set to use monospace font Courier; then the fo:inline uses ZapfDingbats.

Maybe there's an easier way to use a bunch of fonts without defining them (fop font config?) but I'm not familiar with it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family="SansSerif" font-size="10pt">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master margin-right="0.5in" margin-left="0.5in" margin-bottom="1in" margin-top="1in" 
          page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in" master-name="main">
        <fo:region-body margin-top="1cm"/>
        <fo:region-before extent="1cm"/>
        <fo:region-after extent="1.5cm"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>

  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="main" font-family="Courier">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <fo:block>This is a &amp;#x2666; hex (&amp;#9830; decimal): 
        <fo:inline font-family="ZapfDingbats">&#9830;</fo:inline>
      </fo:block>
      <fo:block>Here is &amp;#x25C6;: 
        <fo:inline font-family="ZapfDingbats">&#x25C6;</fo:inline>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>

</fo:root>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-references) in your XML to produce the ◆ character ([Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) U+25C6 Black diamond).

```
&#x25C6;
```

Comment: Hi jukka,

i am not sure how to use unicode in my xsl fo
will be helpful if there is any reference site or tutorial on this

Comment: @lourdh, you can use the character reference directly in your XSL-FO markup. Example: <fo:block>Some text here. &#x25C6; Some more text.</fo:block>

Comment: @Jukka how do you go about getting that glyph working when calling FOP? I have always set an inline font (see my answer) and I'm curious if you use a different, more robust, method

Comment: @ljdelight, I have never actually needed to use that specific glyph. For FOP, I configure it to use and embed the fonts that I need. If I ever needed to use U+25C6 for real, I would probably take a look at the DejaVu fonts, since they have a good coverage of Unicode and a free license: http://dejavu-fonts.org/